# Change recipient based on Contact Form 7 dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

I have a form on a WordPress site using Contact Form 7. I have a dropdown to choose a recipient but I don't want the email address listed there.

The recipients are listed from a custom post type and when the form is submitted I need to look up the email address based on the selection name. I've got the following code but it's not changing the recipient.

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
   $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance(); 
   $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data(); 
   if( $posted_data["your-recipient"] == 'General Enquiry' ) { 
      $recpage = get_page_by_title('James');
      $recipient_email = $recpage->email_address;
   } else {
      $recpage = get_page_by_title($posted_data["your-recipient"]);
      $recipient_email = $recpage->email_address;
   }
   $properties = $contact_form->get_properties();
   $properties['mail']['recipient'] = $recipient_email;
   $contact_form->set_properties($properties);
   return $contact_form;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```

Any idea why this doesn't alter the recipient address? Thanks.

Comment: If `$posted_data["your-recipient"]` is a dropdown, then you want to use `$posted_data["your-recipient"][0]`

Comment: Thanks Howard, that does seem correct but still not sending - if I remove all 'get_page_by_title' code and just put in email addresses it still doesn't change the recipient so think there's something else amiss or it's not firing the function at all.

Comment: You don't need to return anything... And wpcf7_before_send_mail is an action not a filter. Try changing to add_action

Comment: Thanks Howard - I noticed that from another post and have changed that. It looks as though the process is refusing to send to any address not noted as the admin of the site - assume a security thing but a bit of a problem as not all addresses will be for the site domain. Will investigate that

Comment: Howard - I realised that get_page_by_title requires extra parameters when looking for custom post types - everything now good. If you can add your initial suggestion as an response I'll approve it as the solution - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your select data is posted as an array, since about 2020 with CF7.  So you'll need to access the first value `[0]` of that array to get the dropdown values.  Also, as you commented, you need the third parameter of `get_page_by_title`, and finally you don't need to use `return` in your function, since it will execute your code and apply changes as needed to the objects.  `wpcf7_before_send_mail` is an action hook, not a filter.

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    if ( 'General Enquiry' === $posted_data['your-recipient'][0] ) {
        $recpage         = get_page_by_title( 'James', OBJECT, 'your_CPT' );
        $recipient_email = $recpage->email_address;
    } else {
        $recpage         = get_page_by_title( $posted_data['your-recipient'][0], OBJECT, 'your_CPT' );
        $recipient_email = $recpage->email_address;
    }
    $properties                      = $contact_form->get_properties();
    $properties['mail']['recipient'] = $recipient_email;
    $contact_form->set_properties( $properties );
    // Do not return anything, since this is an action and not a filter.
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```